# I cannot create a label for my application compiled by CodeDom

Tags: c#, winforms, codedom

im making a simple form compiler with codedom. Everything is fine and form is working very well but I can create a "label" here is my application's decompiled code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Neutron
{
public class NeutronX : Form
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new NeutronX());
    }

    public NeutronX()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new Label();
        base.SuspendLayout();
        base.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6f, 13f);
        base.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
        base.ClientSize = new Size(400, 378);
        base.MaximizeBox = false;
        base.Name = "Form";
        base.ShowIcon = false;
        this.Text = "Form";
        this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        base.ResumeLayout(false);
        base.PerformLayout();
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new Point(187, 62);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new Size(49, 21);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
        this.label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        this.label1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 64);
        this.label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
        this.label1.Visible = true;
    }
    public Label label1;
   }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I tested everything but got nothing...

Comment: `this.label1` does not exist, you need to add a class member `Label label1` first. The same would apply for any control you add to the form.

Comment: @RonBeyer I added it already and called "public Label label1;" in down of the code

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: I dont see `this.Controls.Add(this.label1)`.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Is right, if it isn't showing up on the form, but no error, you need to add it to the controls collection.

Comment: @ZorgoZ oh yes i forgot it, BTW thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to have it as answer too. It is not enough to crete the control you need to add it to the control tree to be shown and handled by the message loop. In your case to the form control list. Just add:

```
 this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
```

Comment: Thanks, i really forgot this :)